# Error connecting to the Server in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to add a connection to the server in postgreSQL. But when I fill all the details I get this error

```
Error connecting to the server: FATAL: role "abc" does not exist.
```

"abc" is the username I want to create.

I am using Tomcat server eclipse for this.

Please help me find a solution to this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the user does not yet exist, you will have to login as the admin and [create it](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-add-postgresql-user-account/) before you can login as that user.